# JSON DeserializeObject that has a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

```
[
  {
        "Title": "TOY STORY 4",
        "Genre": "COMEDY",
        "Actors": [
            "Tom Hanks",
            "Tim Allen",
            "Annie Potts"
        ],
        "Id": 1
    },
    {
        "Title": "The Matrix",
        "Genre": "Action",
        "Actors": [
            "Keanu Reeves",
            "Laurence Fishburne",
            "Carrie-Anne Moss"
        ],
        "Id": 2
    }
]
```

I have this JSON string that I want to convert C# object  :

```
public class Movies1
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genre{ get; set; }
    public List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Actor
{
    public string Actors { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

My deserialize code :

```
List<movies> = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movies1>>(json);
```

I am getting the following error :

> "ExceptionMessage": "Could not cast or convert from System.String to
> XXXXX.Models.Actor.",
> "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
> "StackTrace": "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object
> value, Type
> initialType, Type targetType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object
> initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)\r\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader
> reader, Object
> value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)"

Comment: It seems to me that you've answered it for yourself: it has a list of strings. Not a list of complex object `Actor`, but a list of `string`.

Comment: `public List<string> Actors { get; set; }`

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it as a new question. You should not ask multiple questions within a single question (this question is about deserializing JSON), and you shouldn't edit your question to invalidate existing answers because you want something wildly different that you didn't mention in your original question.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the `Actors` is a list of strings, what you need is something like this:

```
public class Movies1 
{
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string GENRE { get; set; } 
    public List<string> Actors { get; set; } 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    
{
    public List<Movies1> Movies { get; set; } 
}
```

Then:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because entry in "Actors" array cannot be deserialized to Actor class instance. It can be deserialized to string. So in your Movie class you should have "public List Actors { get; set; }".
In my the best approach for this would be to have to sets of classes - one for deserializing JSON with POCO objects. And the other with some additional properties not available in JSON (like adding id for actor since this isn't available in JSON). This way you separate your application's logic from storage and thus making it possible to change JSON format easily as well as evolve your logic without being constrained by JSON format.

Comment: public List<string> Actors { get; set; } So the issue is when I am trying to save my object to DB the table does not contain Actors. I am new to this ..... :(

Comment: @Stefan this seems to be outside the scope of your question. I recommend asking a new one.

Comment: Hi @john I have just updated my question ......

Comment: So your classes are used for interaction with Entity Framework (or similar ORM)? If yes than you definietly should separate classes for JSON storage and database storage.
1. You create new classes (similar to those you have now) with Actors being List<string>.
2. You deserialize JSON to them.
3. You create Movies1 instance based on deserialized instance and save it to database.