# How to store an object that has a field that is list of strings to DB SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I store the following object to database ?
I have try to create a controller with EntityFramework but that does not create a column for Actors. I tried to create a complex object for my Actors list, but then I couldn't deserialize it from JSON because it's a string array in my JSON object.

Could you maybe give me a sample as well ...

```
class Movie
{
 public string Title {get; set;}
 public string GENRE {get; set;}
 public List<string> Actors {get; set;}
 public int id {get; set;}
}

using (var db = new DataContext())
 {
   foreach(Movie movie in Movies)
   {
      db.Movies.AddOrUpdate(movie);
   }
 }
```

Comment: As a related table with a 1-Many relation, in this case, an `Actors` table. If you want to model multiple actors starring in multiple movies, it will have to be a many-to-many relation, which means a `MovieActors` table

Comment: [OP's previous question for context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63665288/json-deserializeobject-that-has-a-list-of-strings). I've edited the question slightly to include this context.

Comment: EF6 OR Ef Core?

Comment: BTW `Actors` may be a list of strings in the DTO, but in any application that actually cares about actors they are going to be separate entities.

Comment: With EF Core, you can configure your model to convert value between the property and the column : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Comment: If the question is `how do I map the actor names to actual Actor entities`, you'll have to use a *different model*. What makes a good message model doesn't necessarily make a good application or database model. You'll have to convert your DTO object to a `Movie` with a `List<Actors>` just to be able to work with actors anyway. You can load all `Actor` objects involved in the `Movie` DTO (let's call it MovieDTO) and add them to the actual Movie class used by your application. Once you do that, you can easily map it to the database

Comment: @Vernou actors are entities, not values. They'll be a separate table to begin with (unless they don't really matter, in which case why are they sent as a *list* from the client?). Just because the API DTO uses actor names doesn't mean the application entities or the database tables should do the same

Comment: Hi All Thank you for yours answer but to be honest I have no Idea what to do. Could some maybe direct me to how to guide or sample code just so that I can make sense, I am new to this ...

Comment: @StefanTredoux try [this web API tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to get yourself started