# Setting up a class for a JSON array in Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, api, json.net

I am able to set up an array for a class when each component in the array has a name (in this case `progname`). The JSON looks like this

```json
"document_prg":{
   "data":[
      {
         "progname":"prog1"
      }
   ]
},
```

The class is set up as follows

```cs
public Programs document_prg { get; set; }

public class Programs
{
    public List<datas> data { get; set; } 

    public class datas
    {
        public string progname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However when the elements in the array don't have a name, I am having difficulty. In the example below, the data element is the word `regional`. But it has no name. Can anyone provide some help on how to set up the class for the JSON String below:

```json
"document_type":[
   "Regional"
],
```

Comment: `public List<string> document_type { get; set; }`  See [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182) for tools you can use to auto-generate classes from JSON samples.

Comment: Deserializing a JSON array of strings to a `List<string>`  property is the same answer as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63665334/3744182) to [JSON DeserializeObject that has a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63665288/3744182).  Closing as a duplicate.